# Вопрос по парсингу сайтов на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Всем привет, помогите с парсингом сайта https://2gis.ru/moscow,я сделал парсер, который работал с одной страницой (или ссылкой), и вроде как удачно парсил. И там на сайте идет постраничная навигация, путем добавление в конце **/page/номер страницы** . Ну я решил сделать так, чтоб парсило  определенное число страниц, которое укажет пользователь. Но у меня не вышло, не могу понять как это сделать, код ниже по моему должен работать, но он не работает и все, либо в циклах проблема, либо запрос session.get не отправляется, не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from time import sleep

class Client:

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.headers = {'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

    def load_page(self):
        url_list = []
        town = input('Введите название города на английском в нижнем регистре : ')
        category = input('Введите название категории : ')
        pages = int(input('Введите примерное число страниц :'))
        
        for page in range(1, pages + 1):
            url = 'https://2gis.ru/' + town + '/search/' + category + '/page/' + str(page)
            url_list.append(url)
        
        print(url_list)

        for url in url_list:
            res = self.session.get(url=url)
            sleep(2)
            res.raise_for_status()
            text = res.text
            self.parse_page(text = text)

    def parse_page(self, text):
        soup = BS(text, 'lxml')
        container = soup.select('div._awwm2v > div > div._y3rccd')
        for block in container:
            self.parse_block(block=block)

    def parse_block(self, block):
        name = block.select_one('span._hc69qa').text
        name_zav = block.select_one('span._oqoid').text
        location = block.select_one('span._tluih8').text
        print(name,' - ',name_zav,' - ',location)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = Client()
    parser.load_page()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что поскольку страница прогружается скриптами, то `requests` в данном случае не поможет. Ниже привожу решение с использованием `selenium`.

> Перед запуском скрипта скачайте [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) для своей OS. (в скрипте использовался браузер Firefox поэтому `geckodriver`. если захотите запилить под Chrome, скрипт нужно будет адаптировать под него и драйвер соответственно нужен будет другой). Поместите распакованный `geckodriver` в папку со скриптом. **И не забудьте установить сам Firefox**

```py
# pip install selenium (если не установлен)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions

opt = FirefoxOptions()
opt.headless = True
site = Firefox(options=opt)
site.implicitly_wait(10)


class Client:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def load_page(self):
        town = input('Введите название города на английском в нижнем регистре : ')
        category = input('Введите название категории : ')
        pages = int(input('Введите примерное число страниц :'))

        url_list = ['https://2gis.ru/{town}/search/{category}/page/{page}'.format(
            page=page,
            town=town,
            category=category
        ) for page in range(1, pages + 1)]

        print(url_list)

        for url in url_list:
            site.get(url)

            table = site.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
            text = table.get_attribute('outerHTML')
            self.parse_page(text=text)

    def parse_page(self, text):
        soup = Soup(text, 'html.parser')

        container = soup.find_all('div', class_='_y3rccd')
        for block in container:
            self.parse_block(block=block)

    def parse_block(self, block):
        name = block.find('span', class_='_hc69qa').text
        name_zav = block.find('span', class_='_oqoid').text
        location = block.find('span', class_='_tluih8').text
        print(name, ' - ', name_zav, ' - ', location)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = Client()
    parser.load_page()
    site.close()
    site.quit()
```

> Не очень понятно зачем Вы создавали класс в данном случае.

Comment: мм но почему тогда парсер с одной ссылкой работал без использования selenium, кстати спасибо за ответ